# Formdata send only the name of the first object

Tags: php, ajax, multipartform-data, form-data

I try to upload files asynchronously but I've got a problem I cannot solve.
I have an input field without form element, it contains raw data and files. When I try to upload, the very first formdata file object fails I guess on server side. the $_FILES variable contains only the name of the first file but after the first everything works fine. Html:

```
<input class="form-control fileInput" id="applInputIdentityFile" type="file" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.png,.gif" style="display: none">
```

JS:

```
$('.fileInput').on('change',function(){
    applToSend.arrayToSend = new FormData();
    $('.fileInput').each(function(){
      var fileName = $(this).val().replace(/^.*\\/, "");
      if(fileName){
        $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "Name").html(fileName);
        $(this)[0].files[0].descr = $(this).attr("id");
        applToSend.arrayToSend.append($(this).attr("id"), $(this)[0].files[0]);
      }
    });
  });
```

The frontend object contains the right values, and the ajax header seems fine for me:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryDcqJbGjmdx2dg3q6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="applInputIdentityFile"; filename="20200430_115117.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryDcqJbGjmdx2dg3q6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="applInputProdCertFile"; filename="20200430_115117_resized.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

the Ajax itself:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: '/application/addAppl',
      type: 'POST',
      data: applToSend.arrayToSend,
      timeout: 30000,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    })
```

but the very first file always fails, doesn't matter how many files I try to upload or which input, which file, which extension I use.
On server side there is only these lines, everything else has been commented out (I use MVC, so it's the model of the request after several hundreds line of code):

```
  public function addAppl($data){
    foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value){
      foreach($value as $kkey=>$vvalue){
        echo "<br>".$key.": ".$kkey." :".$vvalue;
      }
    }
  }
```

```
applInputIdentityFile: name :20200430_115117.jpg
applInputIdentityFile: type :
applInputIdentityFile: tmp_name :
applInputIdentityFile: error :1
applInputIdentityFile: size :0
applInputProdCertFile: name :20200430_115117_resized.jpg
applInputProdCertFile: type :image/jpeg
applInputProdCertFile: tmp_name :/tmp/phpLoBwTl
applInputProdCertFile: error :0
applInputProdCertFile: size :382022
```

Could you help me how to solve this?

Comment: Error `1` means `the uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini` according to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: This was the problem, I set in the .htaccess but only the "local_value", the "global_value" is 1mb. Where can I find these error codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the `upload_max_filesize`

You can edit the htaccess file, add this line

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 256M //256M more or less
```

Or edit the php.ini file, locate this and change it:

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M //256M more or less
```

Comment: It has been already done, the problem still occurs. I checked it with php_ini():
php_value memory_limit 30M
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
The two files I showed you are less than 0.5 megabyte.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the apache server after editing?

Comment: I set them in the .htaccess and I cannot restart, I have a cpanel as communication interface, some ssh features but no direct access to apache or the server. But this is the problem, I was wrong, the first file I tried was bigger than 1mb. I haven't set the global values: ["upload_max_filesize"]=> array(3) { ["global_value"]=> string(2) "1M" ["local_value"]=> string(3) "30M".  Where can I find these error codes? I googled an hour for them and I haven't found. And I guess I'll do another hour to figure out how to set the global_value :).

Comment: Usually php errors are placed in the main public_html under error.log file